# Node Express authentication middleware fails after successful login

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

I have an angular app running on localhost:8000 and a node express api with passport authentication on localhost:3000. After the user login the server returns a successful response but when I try to call other services it fails on the authentication middleware. It doesn't make sense since the login was successful. The user should be authenticated!

Authentication middleware:

```
exports.isAuthenticated = (request, response, next) => {
  if (!request.isAuthenticated()) return next(createError(401, 'Você não está autorizado.'));
  next();
};
```

When I move the api to a real domain everything works. I thinks it's something related to the localhost x localhost connection but don't know what.

Comment: If they are running on different ports the cookies won't be shared.

Comment: How can I handle this since it's not possible to run to apps in same port?

Comment: You shouldn't need to run them on different ports - express is server side running on port 3000, but angular is a client side framework, it should not use a different port.